# taking screenshots without knowing to the user in android application

Tags: android, screenshot

Is there a way to take screen shots of my android application while user using the app and send those screenshots to a server without knowing to the user. Screen shots should be taken at some particular interval of time.

Please give some implementation ideas.

Comment: as far as i remember, taking screenshotsisn't that easy on a non-rooted device, because only "special" apps have the permission to take screenshots (signed by the manufacturer). It's an security issue (screenlogger in android = keylogger on your pc).

One hint to look at: It's been a while since i last tried it, but I think you have to use a native library.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose there is an ImageView or a TextView or some other view like button etc in that particular screen. Then you will be doing like this:

```
View v=img.getRootView(); //img is ImageView. you replace it with your view
v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap bmp= v.getDrawingCache();
```

You have to convert bitmap to `byte[]` and send it to the server.

Comment: This can be used only on the same app where this code is running right?

Comment: yeah. even hemalatha was asking about the same thing in the question. (she mentioned "my application")

Answer (score 0):

By using Below code you can able to take the screen shot:

```
 View root = findViewById(android.R.id.content);
 root.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
 Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(root.getDrawingCache());
 root.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

And you can handle this code as per your requirement. Here bm is the Screen Shot bitmap you can send that bitmap file to your appropriate server and get to know about it.

Enjoy. :)

Answer (score 0):

as u mentioned, u want to take screenshot from ur application, try this.

```
Bitmap bitmap;
View v1 = MyView.getRootView();
v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

MyView is the View through we need include in screen.